# Insertion query not working and if and else both loops are being executed

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert data into a new table based on some criteria. Iam fetching this data from existing table and then storing it in variables.And using these variables, iam inserting it in the new table. The data is getting stored in the variable, but the insert query is not working. Also the if and else loops, both are getting executed.
        
    
    
    -->

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM creg";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["c_fname"]. " " . $row["post"]. " " . $row["c_qualification"]. $row["c_moname"]. " ". $row["c_WorkEx"]. "<br>";
        $id=$row['id'];
        $timestamp=$row['timestamp'];
        $post=$row["post"];
        $qual=$row["c_qualification"];
        $c_fname=$row['c_fname'];
        $c_lname=$row['c_lname'];
        $c_mname=$row['c_mname'];
        $c_moname=$row['c_moname'];
        $c_gender=$row['c_gender'];
        $c_email=$row['c_email'];
        $c_DOB=$row['c_DOB'];
        $c_contact=$row['c_contact'];
        $c_address=$row['c_address'];
        $c_workex=$row['c_WorkEx'];

        $servername = "localhost";

        if($qual=="B.E." && $post=="Diploma teacher")
        {
              echo "The trial echo";echo "<br>";
              echo $c_workex ,$c_fname, $c_lname;
              mysql_query("INSERT INTO eligible (id ,c_fname, c_lname, c_mname, c_moname, c_gender, c_email, c_DOB, c_contact, c_address, c_qualification, c_workex, c_post)
                    VALUES ('$id','$timestamp','$c_fname','$c_lname','$c_mname','$c_moname','$c_gender','$c_email','$c_DOB','$c_contact','$c_address','$qual','$c_workex','$post')");
        }
        else 
        {
              echo "Error";
        }
    }

} 
else 
{
    echo "0 results";
}


$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: what error message(s) are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed this error:

```
(id ,c_fname, c_lname, c_mname, c_moname, c_gender, c_email, c_DOB, c_contact, c_address, c_qualification, c_workex, c_post)

VALUES ('$id','$timestamp','$c_fname','$c_lname','$c_mname','$c_moname','$c_gender','$c_email','$c_DOB','$c_contact','$c_address','$qual','$c_workex','$post')
```

Now `$timestamp` is extra, number of columns you specified are not equal to number of variables...

Comment: I have added timestamp but now also it is not working.

Comment: Also as Wr1t3r mentioned run the query as $conn->query($query); and not with mysql_query...

Comment: thanks it worked!!! But still both  if and else loops are executing at the same time

Comment: can you show me the output you see? also how many records are there in total??

Comment: ELIGIBLE CANDIDATES
id: 1 - Name: Madhura Diploma teacher B.E.Vidula 1 year
The trial echo

1 yearMadhuraPatilid: 2 - Name: Archana Degree teacher B.E.Alka no experience
Error
id: 3 - Name: anuja Diploma teacher B.E.Vidula 2 years
The trial echo

2 yearsanujaPatilid: 4 - Name: Meenakshi Degree teacher M.E.Alka 1 year
Error
id: 5 - Name: Mithila Diploma teacher M.E.Vidula 2 years
Error

Comment: ok its working just perfect!!!

You have `if($qual=="B.E." && $post=="Diploma teacher")` condition
all rows that do not qualify for this condition show `error`
e.g. `id: 5 - Name: Mithila Diploma teacher M.E.Vidula 2 years Error`
here its `M.E.` instead of `B.E.` so the else part is executed...

Comment: If my answers solved your issues, it would be nice if you select my answer as accepted

Answer (score 0):

1. You have used OOP version of mysqli to connect and then inside your loop you are using "mysql_query".
2. Integer values can't have quotes around them...
   so '$id' should be just $id in your query.

Comment: I agree with you, but when I am selecting the values from creg table they (variables)are being displayed properly. Only while inserting it is not working, why so?  also both if and else loops are executing simultaneously